# Generate new Leaflet tiles using existing tile map + overlayed GeoJSON data via browser

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a large number of GeoJSON objects that I am rendering on page load over an existing tile map. This is terribly inefficient and won't scale.

I would like to be able to take the existing tiles, overlay the GeoJSONs, and then export those as a single "layer" to generate a new tile map that I can then reference instead of the base layer. Is this possible in the browser?

The base layer is a standard XYZ format, and the GeoJSONs are zip code boundaries color-coded to attributes my company tracks.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't scale"? Vector layers scales to whatever you want.

Comment: The # of GeoJSONs I want to load won't scale. The browser gets bogged down and will eventually crash. The tiles themselves are great, it's the added complexity of the GeoJSON layer that is the issue.

Comment: The idea to make raster tiles on-the-fly client side, even if there would be such library, does not make much sense. This is something that should be done server side. As far as client side goes, you could try Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) to speed up GeoJSON processing.